How to obtain UTF-8 binary representation of an emoji character?
I am trying to print bits of of UTf-8 character. In that case an emoji.
According to the the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut74oHojxqo
the following code script.py (both from the script edited with vim and the python command line from the terminal
s = ''
print(len(s))
print(s[0])

should give the following output:
$ python script.py 
4
'xf0'

However it gives me
$ python script.py 
1



The video uses Python 2, not 3. In 3 it is a single character. Convert to bytes ''.encode() and use the byte-string.

Yes the code in the video is Python 2, not Python 3. Although why a video uploaded in 2021 is for python 2 beats me. But there are some good take away points in the video: 1) use Unicode aware functions; 2) use grapheme aware functions when maximum accuracy is required. BUT not all Python functions are Unicode aware. Some diverge from Unicode, some are not based on Unicode. Python has no inbuilt support for graphemes, additional packages are needed.

Python 3 equivalent:
s = ''.encode()  # Encode Unicode code points to default UTF-8 encoding.
print(len(s))
print(s.hex(' '))  # hexadecimal display with spaces between bytes.

Output:
4
f0 9f 91 8d

